# Get all descendants of parent in mysql or php?

Tags: php, mysql, parent

Hoping for some help here guys. Say I have a mysql table like so

```
ID | Content | Parent ID |
2  | A       | 0
3  | A       | 2
4  | A       | 3  
5  | A       | 4
6  | A       | 10
7  | A       | 0
8  | A       | 7
9  | A       | 8
10 | A       | 9
```

And I wanted to the all the descendants of ID 2.

3 is the Child. The grandchildren would be any post with the Parent ID 3. And so on.

In this case the descendants of `ID 2` are `ID's 3, 4 and 5`.

And the descendants of `ID 7` are `ID's 8, 9, 10 and 6`

Is there anyway I can query this in MySQL with no limit on the depth of ancestry? Or even iterating through a result-set in php?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

`getTree()` would return the parent node with nested children. You may need to change PHP mysql query based on your framework.

```
public function getTree($nodeId) {
    $mainNode = $this->db->select('id, content')->from('table_name')->where('id', $nodeId)->get()->first_row();
    $this->recur($mainNode);
    return $mainNode;
}

public function recur(&$node) {
    $q = $this->db->select('id, content')->from('table_name')->where('parent_id', $node->id)->get();
    if($q->num_rows() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $node->children = $q->result(); // array of all child nodes
        foreach ($node->children as $u) {
            $this->recur($u);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish like so: (I'll just use pseudocode to give you a rough idea)

```
$res = get_res('select * from my_table');

$descendants = get_descendants(2); 

function get_descendants ($parent_id, $res) {
    foreach ($res as $row) {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            $descendants[] = $row['id']; 
            $descendants = $descendants + get_descendants($row['id'], $res);
        }
    }
    return $descendants;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you must normalize your database 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

i understand your question like this:

**Forum (parent)**
  ----first Forum----
  forum_id = 1
  forum_name = php

**thread (child)**

----First Record----
  thread_id = 20
  forum_id = 1
  ----Next record----
  thread_id = 21
  forum_id = 1

**post (grandchild)**

then you use joins to access up and down 
for example with normalized database 
if you are in the thread table you can access the forum it belongs to 
aswell as the posts in your specific thread all in one query

Comment: OP's existing structure is standard and well supported. your structure requires a new table for every level.